# How do I use types defined by @types/redux-form in React component with Field and FieldArray?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-form, definitelytyped

I'm developing app with React, Redux, Redux-Form and TypeScript. I am struggling to use types defined by package @types/redux-form ([DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped)), especially with FieldArray. There is an attribute "component" where I pass reference to component, but I have no clue what type should I use when describing its props. I downloaded example of using FieldArray from [Redux-Form repository](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form) and slightly modified it to work with TypeScript. I want to compile it with compilerOption "noImplicitAny": true. So here is the FieldArraysForm.tsx (similar to [official example](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/fieldarrays/)):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Field, FieldArray, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import validate from './validate';

const renderField = (props) => {
  const { touched, error } = props.meta;
  const { input, label, type } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <div>
        <input {...input} type={type} placeholder={label} />
        {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

const renderHobbies = (props) => {
  const { fields } = props;
  const { error } = props.meta;
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push()}>
          Add Hobby
        </button>
      </li>
      {fields.map((hobby, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          <button
            type="button"
            title="Remove Hobby"
            onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
          />
          <Field
            name={hobby}
            type="text"
            component={renderField}
            label={`Hobby #${index + 1}`}
          />
        </li>
      ))}
      {error && <li className="error">{error}</li>}
    </ul>
  )
}

const renderMembers = (props) => {
  const { fields } = props;
  const { error, submitFailed } = props.meta;

  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({})}>
          Add Member
        </button>
        {submitFailed && error && <span>{error}</span>}
      </li>
      {fields.map((member, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          <button
            type="button"
            title="Remove Member"
            onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
          />
          <h4>Member #{index + 1}</h4>
          <Field
            name={`${member}.firstName`}
            type="text"
            component={renderField}
            label="First Name"
          />
          <Field
            name={`${member}.lastName`}
            type="text"
            component={renderField}
            label="Last Name"
          />
          <FieldArray name={`${member}.hobbies`} component={renderHobbies} />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

const FieldArraysForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field
        name="clubName"
        type="text"
        component={renderField}
        label="Club Name"
      />
      <FieldArray name="members" component={renderMembers} />
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
          Submit
        </button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
          Clear Values
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'fieldArrays', // a unique identifier for this form
  validate
})(FieldArraysForm)
```

How do I make it work with types?

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution. I'm leaving the answer in case anyone had the same problem as me.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Field, FieldArray, reduxForm, WrappedFieldProps, WrappedFieldArrayProps, InjectedFormProps, GenericFieldArray } from 'redux-form';
import validate from './validate';

interface CustomFieldProps {
  type?: string;
}

const FieldArrayCustom = FieldArray as new () => GenericFieldArray<Field, any>;

const renderField = (props: WrappedFieldProps & CustomFieldProps) => {
  const { touched, error } = props.meta;
  const { input, label, type } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <div>
        <input {...input} type={type} placeholder={label} />
        {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

const renderHobbies = (props: WrappedFieldArrayProps<undefined>) => {
  const { fields } = props;
  const { error } = props.meta;

  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push(undefined)}>
          Add Hobby
        </button>
      </li>
      {fields.map((hobby, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          <button
            type="button"
            title="Remove Hobby"
            onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
          />
          <Field
            name={hobby}
            type="text"
            component={renderField}
            label={`Hobby #${index + 1}`}
          />
        </li>
      ))}
      {error && <li className="error">{error}</li>}
    </ul>
  )
}

const renderMembers = (props: WrappedFieldArrayProps<{}>) => {
  const { fields } = props;
  const { error, submitFailed } = props.meta;

  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({})}>
          Add Member
        </button>
        {submitFailed && error && <span>{error}</span>}
      </li>
      {fields.map((member, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          <button
            type="button"
            title="Remove Member"
            onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
          />
          <h4>Member #{index + 1}</h4>
          <Field
            name={`${member}.firstName`}
            type="text"
            component={renderField}
            label="First Name"
          />
          <Field
            name={`${member}.lastName`}
            type="text"
            component={renderField}
            label="Last Name"
          />
          <FieldArrayCustom name={`${member}.hobbies`} component={renderHobbies} />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

const FieldArraysForm = (props: InjectedFormProps) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field
        name="clubName"
        type="text"
        component={renderField}
        label="Club Name"
      />
      <FieldArrayCustom name="members" component={renderMembers} />
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
          Submit
        </button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
          Clear Values
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'fieldArrays', // a unique identifier for this form
  validate
})(FieldArraysForm)
```

Comment: Explain your changes, instead of simply pasting the resulting code.

Comment: explain why `FieldArrayCustom`

Comment: I have no idea why it works - I found the solution in their github in some examples or tests.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with `redux-form` 8.2.6 and `@types/redux-form` 8.1.5.

But no longer a problem after upgrading to `redux-form` 8.3.8, `@types/redux-form` 8.3.5.