# How can I use FieldArrays with typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-form

I have a form that has 4 fields. I want to use FieldArray to be able to add/remove forms. I am looking at this example but finding it hard to apply to typescript. For example, I am getting an error for having the lambda function being inside the onClick as this is now forbidden in ts. Do I need to use interfaces?

Many thanks in advance.

````
import { Field, FieldArray, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import validate from './validate'

const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} type={type} placeholder={label} />
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
)

const renderHobbies = ({ fields, meta: { error } }) => (
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push()}>
        Add Hobby
      </button>
    </li>
    {fields.map((hobby, index) => (
      <li key={index}>
        <button
          type="button"
          title="Remove Hobby"
          onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
        />
        <Field
          name={hobby}
          type="text"
          component={renderField}
          label={`Hobby #${index + 1}`}
        />
      </li>
    ))}
    {error && <li className="error">{error}</li>}
  </ul>
)```
````

Comment: [Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49749060/how-do-i-use-types-defined-by-types-redux-form-in-react-component-with-field-an)

Answer (score 0):

While lambda inside `onClick` are discouraged due to the performance impact you can go for them by disabling the tslint rule `"jsx-no-lambda": false`.

If you prefer to disable the rule only for this file see https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/rule-flags/

The other way is to declare your function inside the map like:

```
{fields.map((hobby, index) => {
    const doSomething = () => fields.remove(index)
    return <li....>
})}
```

(Not sure this will solve the performance though)